# An unwanted guest

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> I am here, but not really
>   My presence is eerie.
>
> Why the long face, why the frustration
>   After all I am only a sensation
>
> You and my body went separate ways
>   I fill out the empty space

***What am I?***

Comment: Can i borrow this riddle for a small puzzle game I'm making ? I would gladly give you full credit for making it :)

Comment: @Nils Munch glad you like the puzzle, please go ahead and use it if you want to, reword it if you think you can make it better

Comment: Done and done :) Thank you. Did rephrase it a little bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit dark... but is it

> Phantom Limb Pain

I am here, but not really My presence is eerie.

> The feeling of the limb is there but not the limb itself. 'Eerie' as a play on the word 'phantom'.

Why the long face, why the frustration After all I am only a sensation

> The associated discomfort is only a sensation. 'Frustration' comes in because there's no way to actually treat it.

You and my body went separate ways I fill out the empty space

> 'My body' = the missing limb itself. The phantom limb pain fills the space that the limb occupied.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> A fart?

I am here, but not really

> It physically exists but you can't see or touch it.

My presence is eerie

> It disturbs and startles people.

Why the long face, why the frustration After all I am only a sensation

> It will not cause you physical harm, but the smell will make you frustrated until it fades.

You and I went separate ways

> It left your body.

I fill out the empty space

> Gas expands to fill the room.

Comment: I am yet to experience an eerie fart

Comment: Some may consider this crude and childish humor, but this is actually quite well thought out and the explanations are pretty sound. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a

> deja vu

It's a bit difficult to explain, but it is a sensation, often eerie. You feel like it's currently happening, but it's not. And the "you and I went separate ways" might mean that:

> you and the "you" from the deja vu are not the same... if you know what I mean.

Comment: How does a deja vu fill out an empty space?

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I think... (Deja vu, anyone? No? Ok...)

Answer (score 1):

What about

> Smell

Because

> Eerie presence, especially if unexplained. Not really here because it can dissipate. It is only a sensation, I assume frustration refers to the frustration of the riddle. After you go somewhere your smell fills the path behind you. Note that this explanation also works for the answer noise assuming you make some noise while walking but smell is what I picked since the word for smell is both the sense of smell and a smell itself (possibly only in slang)

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> A Cold Breeze?

I am here, but not really
My presence is eerie.

> You can just feel the breeze but its not really present. Its just air passing slowly. A cold breeze is often eerie.

Why the long face, why the frustration 
After all I am only a sensation

> No need to get frustrated. Its only a sensation of breeze brushing your skin.

You and my body went separate ways 
I fill out the empty space

> Breeze passes you and the air fills empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> **the Past?**
>  The past exists, but not anymore (philosophically speaking), which makes it scary/eerie for some.
>  Not entirely sure about the third/fourth lines, but I think it has to do with memories, particularly bad ones that cause grief.
>  You and your past go separate ways - while you go forward in time, the past is always backwards. Also, the past is always in the space between what once was the past and where you are in the present.

Comment: Past is not a sensation

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Darkness

---

I am here, but not really

> Darkness doesn't really exist, it's more a lack of light

My presence is eerie

> Many people are scared of the dark due to the unknowing of what it hides

Why the long face, why the frustration 
After all I am only a sensation

> Possibly the hinting at the fear of the unknown, hidden by darkness

You and I went separate ways

> Your shadow, which is made of darkness is going away from you

I fill out the empty space

> Everything that does not have light is filled with darkness

Comment: Darkness doesn't explain the sensation part

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> a bad dream

I am here, but not really
My presence is eerie.

> Correct for a bad dream.

Why the long face, why the frustration 
After all I am only a sensation

> Bad dreams can make you frustrated, and dream a kind of sensation(not sure)?

You and I went separate ways 
I fill out the empty space

> When you wake up dream is gone, but stays in memory(empty spaces of our memory).

Comment: It doesn't fit the sensation part

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Loneliness?

I am here, but not really

> It's the feeling when no one is around

My presence is eerie.

> Loneliness is a uncomfortable feeling

Why the long face, why the frustration 
After all I am only a sensation

> The sensation of loneliness can make you sad or frustrated

You and my body went separate ways 
I fill out the empty space

> When we leave each other, then I'd be alone (not sure what loneliness's "body" is though)

Comment: Doesn't fit the separate ways part of the riddle

Comment: Figured as much :)